# Python Iteration Through List

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, pypi

Trying to iterate a list from pytrends but getting search volume numbers and concatenating a message.

Problem is the output is iterating through the keyword but the data only reflects the first word.

Want:

```
Search Decrease Alert: For Apple, last week average search interest was 48.25, a -6.8% weekly decrease.
Search Decrease Alert: For Google, last week average search interest was 10.75, a -6.5% weekly decrease.
```

Getting:

```
Search Decrease Alert: For Apple, last week average search interest was 10.75, a -6.5% weekly decrease.
Search Decrease Alert: For Google, last week average search interest was 10.75, a -6.5% weekly decrease.
```

Any idea the issue?

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd                        
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrends = TrendReq()

#input your terms
kw_list = ['Apple','Google']

#enter the region
geo = 'US'

#define lookback period
look_back = 8

#define increase threhsold
increase_threshold = 0.01

#define decrease threshold
decrease_threshold = -0.01

#######################################################logic

#hit the google trends api to extract the data
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat = 0, timeframe = 'today 5-y', geo = geo, gprop='') 
data = pytrends.interest_over_time().reset_index()

#remove current week as it may be partial
data = data[:-1]

#remove "isPartial" column
data = data.iloc[:, 0:2]

#create moving average for search volume index
data['Moving Average'] = data.rolling(look_back, min_periods=1).mean()

#calculate moving average for search volume index 
data['Moving Average Percent Change'] = data['Moving Average'].pct_change()

#extract the most recent week
last_week = data.iloc[-1:]

#extract last week's search volume
last_week_moving_average = last_week['Moving Average']

#extract the percent difference
change = last_week['Moving Average Percent Change']

#######################################################
```

```
#flag if moving average search volume index is above or below thresholds
for k in kw_list:
    for m in last_week_moving_average:
        for i in change:
            if i >= increase_threshold:
                #print('above')
                print('Search Interest Alert: For ' + str(k) + ', last week\'s average search interest was ' + str((m)) + ', a ' + str("{:.1%}".format(i)) + ' weekly increase.')
            elif i <= decrease_threshold:
                print('Search Decrease Alert: For ' + str(k) + ', last week average search interest was ' + str((m)) + ', a ' + str("{:.1%}".format(i)) + ' weekly decrease.')
            else:
                print('No Alerts')
```

I'm not sure if the issue is because Google puts a limit on the number of entries or if there's a problem with my for loop.

Comment: What does `print(list(change))` look like? Do you see all the values you expect in the list? If it looks meaningful, will you edit your question and add the output of that? Along those lines, for debugging, comment the `if ... elif ... else` and just print *every* change, as a sanity check.

Comment: Also, once you get the trends from pytrends with `kw_list`, `kw_list` isn't tied to the data. You're just printing `k`, but you're not using `k` to get data for that key-word only. The issue might not be in your loop. It also looks like you might not fully understand what your data's structure is. Go back, _before_ the loop, and make sure that you can manually get any `change` for any `kw`... can you print _all_ the changes for 'Apple'?